# Regular Expression for parsing a sports score

Tags: regex

I'm trying to validate that a form field contains a valid score for a volleyball match. Here's what I have, and I think it works, but I'm not an expert on regular expressions, by any means:

```
r'^ *([0-9]{1,2} *- *[0-9]{1,2})((( *[,;] *)|([,;] *)|( *[,;])|[,;]| +)[0-9]{1,2} *- *[0-9]{1,2})* *$'
```

I'm using python/django, not that it really matters for the regex match. I'm also trying to learn regular expressions, so a more optimal regex would be useful/helpful.

Here are rules for the score:
1. There can be one or more valid set (set=game) results included
2. Each result must be of the form dd-dd, where 0 <= dd <= 99
3. Each additional result must be separated by any of [ ,;]
4. Allow any number of sets >=1 to be included
5. Spaces should be allowed anywhere except in the middle of a number

So, the following are all valid:
25-10 or 25 -0 or 25- 9 or 23 - 25 (could be one or more spaces)
25-10,25-15 or 25-10 ; 25-15 or 25-10 25-15 (again, spaces allowed)
25-1 2 -25, 25- 3 ;4 - 25 15-10

Also, I need each result as a separate unit for parsing.  So in the last example above, I need to be able to separately work on:
25-1
2 -25
25- 3
4 - 25
15-10

It'd be great if I could strip the spaces from within each result.  I can't just strip all spaces, because a space is a valid separator between result sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://regex101.com/r/fml5Bm/3) is solution for your problem.

```
str.replace(r"(\d{1,2})\s*-\s*(\d{1,2})", "$1-$2")
```

How it works:
`(\d{1,2})` capture group of 1 or 2 numbers.
`\s*` find 0 or more whitespace.
`-` find -.

`$1` replace content with content of capture group 1
`$2` replace content with content of capture group 2

you can also look at [this](https://regex101.com/r/fml5Bm/4).

Comment: That is certainly much more simple than the mess I came up with.  I'll test it today against various permutations of possible score inputs. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Thats nice :) if it works for you please accept answer to appreciate answer with some points ;P

Comment: Your string didn't exactly replace mine, but it lead me to a much better solution:

Comment: Your string didn't exactly replace mine, but it lead me to a much better solution: First, I strip all white space with re.sub('\s+', '', myString), then I use [most of] your regex to validate the stripped form field against: r'^\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}([,;]\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})*$'.  Thank you for the assistance!